# Mergeo de arrays JSON obteniendo otros arrays en PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy recibiendo tres arrays desde JSON y quería saber si es posible mergearlos (no concatenarlos) y a su vez crear arrays resultantes es decir, si recibo esto:

```
$jsonIdProducto = array("id_producto"=>"3","id_producto"=>"2","id_producto"=>"1");
$jsonSubtotal   = array("subtotal"=>"27","subtotal"=>"28","subtotal"=>"40");
$jsonCantidad   = array("cantidad"=>"3","cantidad"=>"4","cantidad"=>"5");
```

y necesito guardar el pedido en una tabla requiero obtener algo como esto para usarlo en un foreach que me lo guarde todo en 3 filas distintas. Por ello me gustaría poder obtener algo así, es posible?

```
$array1 =array("id_producto"=>"1","subtotal"=>"40","cantidad"=>"5");
$array2 =array("id_producto"=>"2","subtotal"=>"28","cantidad"=>"4");
$array3 =array("id_producto"=>"3","subtotal"=>"27","cantidad"=>"3");
```

La función array_merge me devuelve una fusión correcta pero solamente de una fila asi:

```
array ( 'id_producto' => '1', 'subtotal' => '40', 'cantidad' => '5', )
```

Comment: También tienes `array_merge_recursive` , puedes probarlo?

Comment: Es imposible obtener un `array` como este en `php` `array("id_producto"=>"3","id_producto"=>"2","id_producto"=>"1")` dado que es un array asociativo, solo puede haber un `"id_producto"` como `key`, estás seguro que así es como obtienes la respuesta del json, incluso en json no se podría algo así?

Comment: @Jakala `array_merge_recursive` me devuelve solamente el `array3 Array ( [id_producto] => 1 [subtotal] => 40 [cantidad] => 5 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, es prácticamente imposible que tengas un `array` de esta manera ya que como es un `array` asociativo, cada vez que se inserte un nuevo valor en el mismo key se reemplazada con el nuevo valor y el viejo se "destruye":

**Esto esta mal**

```php
$jsonIdProducto = array("id_producto"=>"3","id_producto"=>"2","id_producto"=>"1");
```

**Esto esto esta bien:**

```php
$jsonIdProducto[] = ["id_producto"=>"1"];
$jsonIdProducto[] = ["id_producto"=>"2"];
$jsonIdProducto[] = ["id_producto"=>"3"];
```

Digamos que tienes el array de la siguiente manera (De la manera correcta).

```php
$jsonIdProducto[] = ["id_producto"=>"1"];
$jsonIdProducto[] = ["id_producto"=>"2"];
$jsonIdProducto[] = ["id_producto"=>"3"];

$jsonSubtotal[] = ["subtotal"=>"27"];
$jsonSubtotal[] = ["subtotal"=>"28"];
$jsonSubtotal[] = ["subtotal"=>"40"];


$jsonCantidad[] = ["cantidad"=>"5"];
$jsonCantidad[] = ["cantidad"=>"4"];
$jsonCantidad[] = ["cantidad"=>"3"];

$result = []; //Resultado de iterar todos los 3 arrays
$arrayCount = count($jsonIdProducto) - 1; //Vemos cuantas posiciones tiene el primer array

for($i = 0; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++){
    $result[] = [
        "id_producto"=> $jsonIdProducto[$i]["id_producto"],
        "subtotal"=>$jsonSubtotal[$i]["subtotal"],
        "cantidad"=> $jsonCantidad[$i]["cantidad"]
    ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Esto almacena las posiciones que quieres dentro de un nuevo array.

**Resultado**

```php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_producto"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_producto"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_producto"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["subtotal"]=>
    string(2) "40"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Hay algunas advertencias con respecto a esto, como tienes 3 `array` como indicas, estos 3 siempre deben tener la misma cantidad de posiciones que el primer array `$jsonIdProducto`.

Puedes probarlo en el patio de juegos del PHP Sandbox [DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62ee66fec03d180451694973cd47050e7d590944)

Comment: Correcto, estaba interpretando mal el array que recibía. Muchas gracias